# Implementing Jquery Javascript code that will populate a link that will ensure ASP.NET MVC action redirect to ASP.NET Web form page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Our company has an ASP.NET Web Forms application, and we want to ensure that any new features and new pages use ASP.NET MVC framework, therefore, we have to make sure that ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC work well together in our application.

We have a logout link:

```
   <div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="MvcLogoutLinkClass">Logout</a>
        </div>
```

on page load the following javascript code is executed:

```
$(".MvcLogoutLinkClass").click(function () {
    sessionStorage.clear();

    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Logout", "Home")';
    return false;
});
```

The URL action is supposed to call:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            return Redirect("~/Logout.aspx");

        }

    }
```

Unfortunately, the url renders as follows:

```
http://localhost:50000/(F(32v4pHftR1WUUxm9iOOg_XZprufVxkTGjbZHW3B98h5TZerx_L9knjrb_TpRCRw8e9cQxehNuJZOfr70qEtS3x7SA9XbVoZvh2-Dx1FaBmzXsPkI7CtsWGjAD9aUt-l9swq7GQIoODKXVT0dki43EbjrmR873i8mQ3oQDI42ZWgsxsyro4vTZr7-NbeKZjGp0))/MVC/Core.MVC.Controllers/Home/@Url.Action(%22Logout%22,%20%22Home%22)
```

which is Not correct because the browser states:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

1) Within the Jquery Javascript, what should I change in the following jquery Javascript code in order to make  Url Action invoke the asp.net mvc action called Logout

```
 window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Logout", "Home")';
```

2) Also, if the following will Not redirect to the ASP.NET Webform page then please tell me what I should change.

```
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        return Redirect("~/Logout.aspx");

    }
```